# How to maximum values of multiple vectors element wise

Tags: r, vector, max

Hi I would like to find a maximum values for each element from multiple vectors. For example:

```
v1<-c(1,1,3,5,10)
v2<-c(10,2,1,1,5)
v3<-c(11,4,2,1,9)
list_of_vectors <- list(v1, v2, v3)
```

I would like the result to be:

```
vmax<-c(11,4,3,5,10)
```

I know that there is the `pmax` function, so I tried it. Because I have the vectors as a list, I did it like this:

```
do.call(pmax, list_of_vectors, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But there is an error with the solution. How can I solve this?

Comment: I thought you didn't want `pmax` so I gave an alternative too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the vectors are always the same length and are in a list as individual elements, then

```
matrixStats::colMaxs(do.call(rbind, l1))
#[1] 11  4  3  5 10
```

or your way,

```
do.call(pmax, c(l1, na.rm=TRUE))
#[1] 11  4  3  5 10
```

where

```
dput(l1)
list(c(1, 1, 3, 5, 10), c(10, 2, 1, 1, 5), c(11, 4, 2, 1, 9))
```